# ASP.NET page working in Firefox and not in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

We were deploying our ASP.NET web app onto a new production server today. In our test server, the pages were working fine on both IE and Firefox.

But now in the production server the main welcome page loads and to enter the application which has a submit/enter button in it does not work in IE and shows a page not found exception.

The same link is working fine in Firefox. We are using css and JavaScript and i have read that they may cause problems.

But i wonder how i did not have any issues with both IE/Firefox in my test server.

Please advice on how to solve this.

Comment: I don't suppose you could share some code/links with us, so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: not enough info supplied

Comment: there is no link that i could give. Its just this. through IIS in my production server i have deployed the website, i m trying to access it from my client i.e my local PC. The same production server link works perfectly with firefox but fails in IE

Comment: Have you checked that IE is not in "Work Offline" mode?

Comment: as the main page opens, its not in offline mode, i have checked it anyways..

Answer (score 3):

You could use fiddler to compare the request made by the two browsers, and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got different proxy settings in each browser, check they these are the same.

I would guess that IE has been set up to use your corporate proxy, and that you need to either configure that proxy to be able to access the new production servers (are they in a DMZ?) or not put in a "bypass proxy for these urls" rule on your own computer...

Comment: i have a main welcome page which is opening in both the browsers, only when i click on the "submit/open" button to redirect to another page does IE fail.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL in IE on the page that is giving the error. Is it the correct URL? If not; try to trace back why. Is there maybe some javascript involved in setting the target URL? Then that would be the first place to start looking.

If it's all in server code, you may want to review the code and look for places where a HttpException is thrown.

You may also want to check the event log on the production server to see if there were any unhandled exceptions.

One more thing that can trip you up is IE's security settings. A local test server may be viewed in the 'Local Intranet' or 'Trusted sites' security level while the production server maybe in the more restricted 'Internet' settings. Try adding the production site to the list of trusted sites and see if that helps.